# Em um modelo MVC 4 C# Web Aplication, em qual camada pode fica o arquivo ADO.NET Entity Data Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Em qual camada eu coloco ele? 
Modelo controle ou view?

ADO.NET Entity Data Model o que faz a conexão com o banco.

Comment: eu não colocaria na View e nem no Model.. na verdade colocaria em uma camada de repositório... chamada pelo controller

Comment: Recomendo a leitura: [Operações CRUD no ASP.NET MVC 5 com o ADO.NET](https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/operacoes-crud-no-asp-net-mvc-5-com-o-ado-net/)

Answer (score 0):

Em um projeto bem estruturado a camada responsável ao acesso a dados ficar no Infra.Data.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode usar o [DDD](http://dddcommunity.org/) para criar uma aplicação seguindo uma abordagem de modelagem de software.

Veja o exemplo completo de do modelo DDD [aqui](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2014/10/tutorial-asp-net-mvc-5-ddd-ef-automapper-ioc-dicas-e-truques/).